# How do you view the exterior of your ship in the Xbox One (not PC) version of Elite Dangerous?

Tags: xbox-one, elite-dangerous

I've seen lots of videos and screenshots from the PC version where the player has a freelook external view of their ship.

This is **not** the constrained view you get during outfitting. They can move the camera as they wish.

How do I get this view on the Xbox One?

Answer (score 4):

I found it <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>Left Bumper</kbd> - you get a warning prompt the first time you use it that it is a debug feature..

**Update:** Following the CQC update this appears to have changed to <kbd>B</kbd> + <kbd>D-Pad-Right</kbd>